# How to access / use the Camera on a Windows 8 Tablet with Java?

Tags: java, windows, camera, tablet

Is there a way to access the Camera of a Windows 8 Tablet (and 8.1) from a Java app?

Right now i am forced to write a Java Client App that runs on a "true" Windows Desktop machine as well as on a mobile Windows 8 / 8.1 Tablet.
On the Tablet the app should be able to use the integrated Camera of the tablet.

Normaly i do those things with Android which is pretty easy, but i have no idea about how to do those things on a Windows machine (i am not used to MFC, etc).

To make this clear:

i do not need/want to fully integrate the Camera into the app! It would be sufficient if i click a Button in my GUI that launches the default Camera app.
And (if possible) returns the image/video recorded to the app.

**Edit:**

as stated in the comment below some clarification about the "return an image/video taken by the camera":

the goal is to click on a button in the app that launches the system default camera app (i know how to launch system-default-programms in windows using Java but i have no clue how windows 8 calls/handles camera apps like android does).
with that app the user takes 0 - X fotos / videos and after he terminates the camera app those images and/or video files should be recognized/received by the Java app.

i hope this makes it a little bit more clear.

Comment: Very vague. "returns the image/video recorded to the app". Returns... how? Right now your question basically reads "How do I start another process from Java", that it will be an application that does things and stuff with the camera is entirely not interesting at this point until you specify what "returns" is.

Comment: i will edit the question to be more precise.
to goal is to get the "finished" images/videos (files) recorded with the camera. for example a jpg-file.
can be one file per use, might be more (for example 5 fotos before the user terminates the camera app).